# Ionic 2 fileTransfer.download not reacting on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2, file-transfer, ionic-native

I've developed an Ionic 2 App on Android and am now trying to bring it to work on iOS.

The App downloads alot of files on initial login and I do that with the [Ionic-Native Transfer plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/). On Android everything works fine, but on iOS the App seems to stuck in the promise of the fileTransfer.download() function, it doesnt even throw an error.

Example Code:

```
private downloadFile(downloadURL: string, filename: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.fileTransfer.download(downloadURL, this.file.dataDirectory + filename, true).then(_ => {
            console.log("download of " + filename + " complete");
            resolve("download finished");
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            reject("download error");
        });
    });
}
```

I also tried to use the this.file.documentsDirectory instead for iOS but I still dont get any error or success outputs.

The downloadURL's are from an firebaseStorage link but I also tested it with a usual download URL.

I assume it does have something to do with permissions, but have not found a solution yet. The other assumption would be, that there is a limit to multiple threads on iOS there are about betwenn 30-100 promises live.

But the strange thing are the missing error messages, it just get stuck and not a single download finishes.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I still have not figured out the cause of the problem, but in the meantime, Ionic released a new version of the Transfer Plugin, which is now called FileTransfer in the official docs. Once I changed my code to use the new FileTransfer plugin, the problem disappeared.

I hope this helps others who faced the same problem.

Comment: Have you seen some of Josh Morony videos debugging Ionic apps whilst running on iPhone ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9J8AxhDxtTE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks for that link, I kind of solved my problem now, by updating to the newest FileTransfer Plugin of Ionic which was released between the time of my first post and today. I edited my post above.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You know can answer your own question. Others upvoted/favourited  this. So if they see this as answered it'll help them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have not figured out the cause of the problem, but in the meantime, Ionic released a new version of the Transfer Plugin, which is now called FileTransfer in the official docs. Once I changed my code to use the new FileTransfer plugin, the problem disappeared.

I hope this helps others who faced the same problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem even with the new ionic-native FileTransfer plugin.

Comment: same problem here with FileTransfer plugin and still no working on ios